# C# - Serializing and Deserializing Linq Tables whilst maintaining Relationships

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, serialization, entity-relationship, datacontractserializer

I want to Test my code! A noble goal I'm sure you agree.

I need to mock out DataContexts for my Regression tests, running the test will verify that for any code change, given the same input we produce the same output.

I'm using [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) to mock out my data contexts. It's awesome and simple, I recommend it, I might move to [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) if it's more lightweight but that's another story.

To get data for my [Mocked Data Contexts](http://www.dimecasts.net/Content/WatchEpisode/170) I want to serialize a small amount of live data stored in an MSSQL DB. To allow the Linq-To-SQL classes to be serialized I use a [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) having set the **Serialization Mode property to Unidirectional** as instructed by [MSFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546184.aspx). This allows me to serialize a row to XML.

When I want to serialize a table I must first pull it into memory by calling *ToList()*. This is because ***Linq.Data.Table* is not itself serializable**.

So now I have a file for each table, I can then Deserialize the XML files and create Linq Tables from the Lists. Then we create a delegate and use that as the implementation for the Mock Data Context. All of this is clearly explained in [this screencast](http://www.dimecasts.net/Content/WatchEpisode/170).

The problem I have is with maintaining relationships between tables, how can I serialize a row with all of its dependencies and then deserialize it in such a way that they're still accessible.

**EXAMPLE**

- In my Live DB I have Tables Customers and Purchases
- There exists a one to many relationship from Customers to Purchases
- In the application code I wish to test I use syntax like;

  var firstCustomerPurchases = Customers.First().Purchases
- This won't work in my test cases with my MockDataContext as the Customers and Purchases tables are just lists which aren't bound to each other.

How can I maintain the relationship throughout the serialization/deserialization process?

Thanks,

Gav

Answer (score 0):

Have you tought about converting your Linq tables into a DataSet, which is serializable and maintains the relationships?